# MySQL foreach INSERT when I have an array from checkboxes.

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a list of checkboxes that I want to insert into a database, which I have processed as an array:

```
<input name="my_array[]" value="<?php echo $data['ID'] ?>" type="checkbox">
<?php echo $data['name'] ?><?php echo "br/>";
```

I'm getting my list of checkboxes from my database, and the selected checkboxes are being posted like so:

```
   $strFoo=$_POST['my_array'];

    $strBar = "";


    foreach ($strFoo as $strFooName) {

    $strBar .= $strFooName . ", ";
    }
    $strBar = substr($strBar, 0, -2);
```

Echoing, I get my list of ID's selected like so `1, 2, 3, 4`

My below foreach is unfortunately only inserting the first ID of the array only..

```
foreach ($strFoo as $strFooName) {

        $strSql="INSERT INTO table (ID) 
                 VALUES ('$strBar')";
    }
```

How can I insert each ID into my table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd have to be:

```
INSERT INTO table (ID) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)
```

so your processing step would need to be

```
$values = array();
foreach ($strFoo as $strFooName) {
     $values[] = '(' . intval($strFooName) . ')';
}

$strBar = implode(',', $values);
```

Note the addition of intval - that ensures that only valid numbers get inserted into the SQL statement. Your version was vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: What would the INSERT statement by with the (1), (2), etc?

Comment: That's mysql's "extended" insert syntax. each `(#)` becomes a new record in the table you're inserting to.

Comment: I see what your saying, but won't that only insert the first 4 INT's selected?

Comment: The loop should generate `(#)` sets for every checkbox selected in th form, since it's looping on strFoo, and that's just a copy of $_POST['my_array']. It'll insert as many checkboxes are selected. It will break if NO checkboxes are selected, however.

Answer (score 0):

`$strSql="INSERT INTO table (ID) VALUES ('$strBar')";`

should be

`$strSql="INSERT INTO table (ID) VALUES ('$strFooName')";`

Answer (score 0):

You're looping in the array with `$strFooName` but you're inserting `$strBar` which is updated just once above.. Maybe it's the problem

Answer (score 0):

From [12.2.5. INSERT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To
>   do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within
>   parentheses and separated by commas. Example:
>
> INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);

That said, however. It looks like you're trying to just loop straight through your post array with this piece of code

```
foreach ($strFoo as $strFooName) {
        $strSql="INSERT INTO table (ID) VALUES ('$strBar')";
}
```

`$strBar` in that example hasn't been created. You might try

```
foreach ($strFoo as $strFooName) {
        $strSql="INSERT INTO table (ID) VALUES ('$strFooName')";
}
```

Although you should also look into preventing SQL injection if you're going to do that.

Comment: Is the code in your question two different attempts, or does the first block of code influence the second?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, I've just changed the $variable it's inserting.